# Exceção ao enviar arquivo Multipart do controller AngularJS no server Spring Boot

Tags: angularjs, upload, spring-boot

Estou com problemas para enviar arquivos (imagens, pdfs) do client side para o server side do meu app.

Sempre que eu tento enviar um arquivo, o Spring me devolve essa exceção:

```
status:"Bad Request"
exception:"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException"
message:"Required request part 'file' is not present"
path:"/upload"
status:400
```

O controller do Spring está assim:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class UploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", 
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {
            if(file != null) {
                System.out.println("Arqiuivo recebido!");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Deu erro!");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    } 
}
```

E também configurei o Multipart resolver assim:

```
 @Bean
 public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
     return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
 }
```

No client side, como estou usando o módulo do `ng-file-upload`, estou usando a seguinte div que consta no github do desenvolvedor:

```
<div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="imagem" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
  ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" 
  ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">Select
</div>
```

E no controller do AngularJS, tenho o seguinte:

```
Upload.upload({
    url: 'upload',
    data: {file: $scope.imagem}
}).progress(function (evt) {

}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Até agora não tive sucesso.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**EDIT**

Tentei usar o Postman pra enviar uma imagem pro server, mas dá a mesma exceção de quando eu tento enviar pelo meu client:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece tudo certo com o seu código java, talvez seja algo no seu client, você já tentou enviar o arquivo por `curl` ou postman?

Comment: adicionei um print screen da tentativa de enviar um arquivo através do Postman, mas também dá a mesma exceção de quando eu tento enviar através do meu client. Você tem alguma ideia se é necessário configurar algo além do `MultipartResolver` no Spring para que o upload funcione?

Comment: Na verdade com spring-boot você não precisa usar esse multipartresolver, veja só aqui http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration. Talvez você só tenha que remover o multipartresolver.